# Apex SOQL return partial result from junction object

Tags: apex, soql, junction-object

I've built a quiz tool using Apex and Lightning Component.
There's a many-to-many relationship between a Quiz_Session__c and a Question_Set__c. The junction object is Quiz_Question_Set__c
From Apex, I'm trying to get all Question Sets. related to a Quiz Session.
For my example, I've a Quiz Session (Id: a0b67000038WMPNAA4) that holds 31 Question Sets.
But the SOQL results return only 30 Quiz Question Set instead of 31

Below is the SOQL Query

```
List<learningXP__Quiz_Session__c> quizs =  

                [SELECT Id,
                Name
                (SELECT Id,
                learningXP__Question_Set__r.Id,

                FROM learningXP__Quiz_Question_Sets__r
                )
                FROM learningXP__Quiz_Session__c
                WHERE ID = :quizId];
```

And the SOQL result (Chrome console)

```
Quiz_Question_Sets__r:
done: false
nextRecordsUrl: "/services/data/v53.0/query/01g670000ErTpngAQC-30"
records: (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
totalSize: 31
```

Can you please explain why? Are junction object records limited to 30 records from a SOQL query?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm Looks like you need to just call `nextRecordsUrl` until you get all results.

Comment: http://cropredysfdc.com/category/salesforce/rest/ This also could be helpful: `due to payload volume, there can be less records returned`.

Comment: I'm not calling REST api directly, I'm using SOQL apex to query the records. Plus shouldn't a soql query return max 10, 000 records? It's strange that I have to paginate for 31 records only.

Comment: I've tested the query on workbench and it returns  all the 31 records as expected

Comment: Can you, please, add lightning component to your question (exact place where you query records through Apex class) + Apex class method implemented? Btw, SOQL query can return 50k records at once.

Comment: If it's `sforce.connection.query(q);` - it is done through API and per documentation in has limited payload.